# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function next() on array in

Tags: php, redbeanphp

конкретно в этом участке кода выдает ошибку. Ничего нового не подключал, Open Server перезагружал, PHP-код выше работает, но здесь выдает ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function next() on array in D:\OSPanel\domains\nikanorov\src\cab.php:100 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\nikanorov\src\cab.php on line 100

100ая строка - это while($favVideo = $favorites -> next()){
Пользуюсь RedBean PHP, подключение к бд есть, весь цикл пробовал удалять и вместо него прописывал dump(). В этом случае то же самое писал только не про "next()", а про "dump()".
В переменной $favorites должен находиться массив с данными из БД.
Если пишу "echo $favorites;", выводит просто надпись "array"

Вот код:

```
$favorites = R::findLike('favorites', array('user' => array($_SESSION["logged_id"])));
while($favVideo = $favorites -> next()){    
$videoId = $favVideo->video;
$ourVideo = R::load('videos', $videoId);
echo '<div class="favorites__block-slider">
<div class="favorites__element-slider">
<div class="favorites__video-slider">' . $ourVideo->path . '</div>
<div class="favorites__wrapper">
<p class="favorites__name-slider"> ' . $ourVideo->name . ' </p>
<p class="favorites__descr-slider"> ' . $ourVideo->descr . ' </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="favorites__wrapper">
<form class="favorites__del-form" action="addvideos.php" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" value="'. $favVideo->id .'" name="favVideoId">
<input class="lessons__del button" type="submit" value="Удалить из избранных" name="deleteFav">
</form> 
</div>
</div>';        
} 
?>
```

Comment: в переменной `favorites` должно находитсят нечто, имеющее метод `next()` а не массив, то есть какой-то объект датасета из R. Видимо `findLike` у вас какой-то самописный фаиндер для модели, и в нем наверное в конце не стоило вызывать какой-то `->toArray()` к примеру.

Comment: что в favorites ? там должен быть объект с методом next()

Comment: не очень понял вас.
Конструкция while($favVideo = $favorites -> next()) используется для перебора массив.
В $favorites в первой строке должен присваиваиваться массив с данными, отобранный из БД.
Например, у меня есть похожий участок кода, в котором всё работает, но используется не R::findLike, а R::findCollection. Различие в том, что findCollection добавляет все данные из таблицы, а findLike только некоторые (в данном случае загружаются из бд только строки со значением $_SESSION["logged_id"] в столбце "user").

Comment: Этот участок кода работает

<?php
$videos = R::findCollection('videos');
while($video = $videos->next() ){ 
$videosPath = $video->path;
$videoId = $video->id;
echo '<div class="lessons__block">
<div class="lessons__video">' . $videosPath . '</div>
<div class="lessons__wrapper">
 <p class="lessons__name"> ' . $video->name . ' </p>
 <p class="lessons__descr"> ' . $video->descr . ' </p>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам php прямым текстом говорит, что вы пытаетесь вызвать `next()` у массива. Сам по себе массив не имеет таких методов.
При этом вы ссылаетесь на `R::findCollection`, но если обратитесь к документации, то увидите, что  `findCollection` возвращает курсор, а не массив.

Поэтому в случае `findCollection` вы пишите `$c->next()` а в случае `findLike()` просто перебираете массив с помощью `foreach`.

по сути разница в том, что в одном случае весь массив целиком загружается в память, либо идет чтение по одной строке. Второе более экономно к памяти и имеет смысл, если у вас какие-нибудь бинарные поля, например, в таблице.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень выручили! PHP нормально не выучил, сразу на RB полез. Пошёл учить)